# What is the speed of crew Dragon upon splashdown?

Tags: spacex, reentry, dragon-v2, parachute, water-landing

After reentry, what is the speed of the Dragon 2 capsule right before splashdown?

What g-force is received upon splashdown?

At the time of writing, [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25473/29286) gives such information for many other crewed spacecraft but not the dragon (the answer is from Feb 18 2018).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [splashes down at 16 mph](https://www.mynews13.com/fl/orlando/space/2023/03/10/nasa-spacex-crew-5-splashdown#:%7E:text=During%20a%20series%20of%20parachute,live%20broadcast%20of%20the%20landing.). That is 25.7 km/h or 7.2 m/s for metric. This was explained during the live broadcast of the Crew-5 mission.

Comment: Added @Speedphoenix