# What is the splash down speed of the manned dragon capsule?

Tags: reentry, landing, soyuz-spacecraft, dragon

What's the rated speed of the crewed dragon capsule? Do we have any data on the actual measurement for the demo mission?

I'd also appreciate any info on speed for Soyuz, other soviet manned, Apollo, mercury capsules, as well as any differences for dragon cargo or dragon with retro rocket landing.

Though at this time my focus is on crewed dragon speed.

Links are appreciated, specially for official sources.

Comment: Note that soyuz don't splash down but land (at less than 24ft/s, its terminal velocity according to [this page](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/structure/elements/soyuz/landing.html) on Nasa website)

Comment: I was aware of the fact, but I don't know of a generic term to describe both splashdown and landing. Is there one?

Comment: This (at least the dragon part) is a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44605/29286, but that one doesn't have an answer either...

Comment: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25473/29286) gives the information you're looking for excluding Dragon

Comment: Should I expect any difference between crewed and cargo in your experiences?

Comment: @Fabio You should expect a difference between Dragon and Dragon 2, since I believe that improved the parachutes and other stuff. 
But I don't think you should expect much difference between crewed Dragon 2 and uncrewed Dragon 2 (so far Dragon 2 has only flown crews or dummy crews, but all CRS resupply missions will use an uncrewed version of Dragon 2)